# Implementing Functor concept in C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20, functor, c++-concepts

Recently I've been trying to create a C++ concept around Haskell's Functor. Something like this:

```
template <template<class>class F>
concept Functor = requires (F<A> f) {
    { fmap(function, f) } -> std::same_as<F<decltype(function(std::declval<A>))>>;
};
```

The problem is with function and A type. If I put them in template declaration than Functor concept depends on them not only on the actual functor F.

Is this sort of thing even possible in C++.

I wish to make this code compile:
`static_assert(Functor<std::optional<int>)` where I already defined fmap on optional.

## Edit

### Clarification

Since people got confused in comments, I will clarify that Functor in this context is Haskell's functor, a type that implements following function:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and not C++ types with overloaded `operator()`. Think of method to convert `std::optional<int>` to `std::optional<std::string>` without unpacking the optional on user level.

### Working solution

Today I made some progress and I was able to write following:

```
template <template<class, class...> class F, class T>
struct Functor {
    template <class Callable>
    [[nodiscard]] static constexpr auto
    fmap(Callable callable, F<T>&& f) -> F<std::decay_t<decltype(callable(std::declval<T>))>>;
};

template <template<class, class...> typename F, class T>
concept FunctorConcept = requires (F<T>&& f) {
    { Functor<F, T>::fmap(std::identity{}, std::forward<F<T>>(f)) } -> std::same_as<F<std::decay_t<decltype(std::identity{}(std::declval<T>))>>>;
};

template <class T>
struct Functor<std::optional, T> {
    template <class Callable>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr static auto
    fmap(Callable callable, std::optional<T>&& f) -> std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(callable(std::declval<T>))>> {
        if (f)
            return callable(*std::forward<std::optional<T>>(f));
        return std::nullopt;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Functor<std::vector, T> {

    template <class Callable>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr static auto
    fmap(Callable callable, std::vector<T>&& f) -> std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(callable(std::declval<T>))>> {
        std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(callable(std::declval<T>))>> result;
        std::transform(begin(std::forward<std::vector<T>>(f)), end(std::forward<std::vector<T>>(f)), std::back_inserter(result), callable);
        return result;
    }
};


int main() {

    static_assert(FunctorConcept<std::optional, int>);
    static_assert(FunctorConcept<std::optional, float>);
    static_assert(FunctorConcept<std::vector, float>);

    return 0;
}
```

I let a separate structure handle fmap overloading and concept just verifies it with `std::identity`.

I am still, unsatisfied with that `std::identity` part. I wonder if there is some other way. Furthermore this code is still easy to break if return type in fmap definition is not the same as the one in the concept. These 2 points can now be considered my question.

Comment: can you explain in C++ terms what you expect from the concept? What is `function` ?

Comment: I think you also need to explain what a Functor is. C++ programmers are usually not very familiar with category theory, and the word "functor" traditionally means something entirely different in the context of C++. (My intuition suspects that it's not possible, though.)

Comment: An example of how you want to use this concept might help explain your intent

Comment: Do you want `Functor<std::optional>` or `Functor<std::optional<int>>` to work? That's a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, as far as I see, that is not possible in the generality that you seek. The reason is that the all-quantifier over type arguments is not sensible in C++ because there will always be *a lot* of types/function combination for which a given template does not represent a Functor:

- function: `[]{}`. `std::optional<void>` is not instantiatable.
- type: `void`. Similar problem: `std::optional` is not a Functor for that.
- type: `int&`. `std::optional` is not a Functor because `std::optional<int&>` does not exist.

Here is an approximation that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
inline auto fmap(auto f, std::optional<T> opt)
    -> std::optional<decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))> {
  if (opt) return f(*opt);
  return std::nullopt;
}

template <template <typename> typename F, typename T>
concept Functor = requires (F<T> f) {
    { fmap([](auto) {return nullptr;}, f) } -> std::same_as<F<decltype(nullptr)>>;
};
```

Here, the input function is fixed to a lambda that always maps to `nullptr`. The type for which the template shall be a Functor must be passed, so this:

```
static_assert(Functor<std::optional,int>);
```

passes, but this:

```
static_assert(Functor<std::optional,int&>);
```

does not.

Of course, this is unsatisfying because even if the `fmap` defined for `std::optional` works on `[](auto) {return nullptr;}` it doesn't mean it will work on the next function.

Comment: I realized that, but I hoped it was not true. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Dragomir: I'm not saying it's definitely not true. I just not see a way to make it not false.